# Create multi array from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i got an array of numbers `[12345,345653,456356]`but i need to convert this to something like `[[1232131],[234324],[67657]]`for using a CSV react component tool that reads data using this format. Do you got some idea how to make this? i tried this using push but i dont get the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array based on existing one:

```js
let input = [12345,345653,456356];
let output = input.map(x => [x]);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as mickl's map() but if you prefer an oldfashioned loop:

```js
let input = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
let output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  output.push([ input[i] ]);
} 

console.log(output);
```